# Масштабирование ширины сайта

Tags: html, css, html5

при масштабировании размера окна браузеера можно заметить скачкообразные изменения ширины сайта (320>768>1200 = размеры заданные контейнеру), **как сделать так чтобы ширина сайта повторяла размер окна браузера, при этом контент оставался в рамках предложенных диапазонов?**
если сделать width: auto, то при увеличении окна браузера контент расплывается по всей ширине.

***ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/iZemil/pink в заглавии ссылка на сайт***

Comment: Вероятно, max-width

Comment: Уберите ширину для `.container`, и установите ему `max-width: 1200px`, например.